# wordpress git style edit and update files

Tags: php, excel, wordpress, git, plugins

I have a WordPress site. There are user levels (0.Basic, 1.Contributor, 2.Researcher, 3.Editor, 4.Admin).

I have data in excel documents. What i need is lvl 2+ registered Users , can edit and add their data to an excel document with out editing the previous data. Now the Admin need to take a notification for that change (Example , username added some data to that file) , see the changes and update or delete the current excel file.

For now the only think im thinking of is that the user sends an excel file via a form upload to the admin and then the admin manually can do the changes.

I wanna know how i can do this cause later on i need to plot those data in charts in specific pages.

Thnx a lot.

Comment: Have you attempted any solutions yet? It would be helpful to see your code or any attempts that you've made.

Comment: The way i have it now, is a submit form for excel files. I don't know if i can combine any plugin to make this happen but if i cant, i will sit down and write code for that.